# Cannot Deploy on Android Emulator Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, emulation

I have this Cross-platform application that deploys fine on both iOS and Android physical devices, but when I try to run it on Android emulator I get this error:

Failed to dlopen Mono runtime from /data/user/0/it.HangoverApp.Hangover/files/.**override**/links/libmonosgen-2.0.so: dlopen failed: "/data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-33RyZeuaossylXX2LQhf0w==/lib/x86/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so" has unexpected e_machine: 3 (EM_386)

I'm currently on Visual Studio Mac 8.8.7, my colleague on Windows is experiencing no problems,
Emulated Device configuration:
Pixel 2 Pie 9.0 - API 28, x86 processor.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version is your mac ?

Comment: MacBook Pro mid 2014 10.15.7 Catalina

Comment: please check Supported Architectures contains x86, about specifying Supported Architectures, please take a look:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/cpu-architectures?tabs=macos#how-to-specify-supported-architectures

Comment: That fixed for me! But isn't x86 deprecated?

Comment: now you solved your problem?

Comment: yes if you post an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Sorry for late response because Chinese New Year， I have post one answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description and error message, I suggest you can check **Supported Architectures** contains x86, about specifying Supported Architectures, you can take a look this thread:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/cpu-architectures?tabs=macos#how-to-specify-supported-architectures